# Careers Spotlight Efficacy

Tags: discussion, jobs

I am curious whether anyone has experience/metrics for spotlighting a company in Careers. Specifically, has it led to

1. Increased volume of applicants, and
2. More importantly, increased volume of *higher quality* of applicants, possibly as a function of (1)?

Any info would be extremely helpful, even if it's just an overall impression!